# Tcsh completion in the format of ls -l

Tags: linux, shell, unix, autocomplete, tcsh

When setting autolist in tcsh.rc, and pressing Tab to complete a filename i get a list of available completions in the format of a "regular" ls command.
is there any way to set tcsh in a way that pressing tab will show a list of available completions in the format of "ls -l"? 
or if not, then just sort the "regular" list by date?

Answer (score 0):

> pressing tab will show a list of available completions in the format of "ls -l"?

No, this is not possible.

Completion in tcsh works by getting a list of words (ie. `my trousers are on fire`), checking if one of the word matches, and then insert that word in the commandline.

There is no functionality which says "display this to the user, but insert something else in the commandline". So while you could complete commands with `ls -l`, this would be fairly useless, since you'll get the entire line in your commandline.

> just sort the "regular" list by date?

This is also not possible, since `tcsh` sorts the completions. You can't disable this ...

Sorry :-( I believe that at least zsh is able to do this, but I'm not sure. Maybe bash can do this as well (but again, not sure).

(This information derived from a careful reading of the manpage, and `tw.parse.c` in the source code.)